# Firebase App Check error in express.js application - appCheck.activate is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-app-check

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: "abcd",
  storageBucket: "efgh",
  databaseURL: "ijklm"
});

const appCheck = admin.appCheck();
appCheck.activate("site_key",true);
```

This is what I have been trying but I get the error mentioned above.